# Best way to open modal if parameter exist, for all routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, modal-dialog

I'm looking for the best solution to open a modal box if some parameter exist in my route. I need to have a global checking for all my route.

It's to open a sharing modal box, for exemple if i got this route :
https://mywebsite.com/my-page/share
I want to open the page with the modal box.
And for this route :
https://mywebsite.com/my-page
just the page

I already use a system for another modal but it's just for one route and with a redirection :

```
 Route::get('/my-register-route', function() {
    if (!Auth::Check()) {
        return redirect('/')->with('modal','register');
    }
    else {
        return redirect('/');
    }
});
```

Is there a solution like this but for all my route, maybe with the Middleware ?

Thanks for your help.